# Property bound to WPF property gets updated, but WPF property does not change

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I need to make a window change position each time the cursor gets over it. I had no problem creating an event trigger for "MouseEnter" which calls a method in the ViewModel. That method changes a double called "RecordingViewTop", and that double is bound to the "Window.Top" property of the xaml file. So it should change window position each time the event is fired, but that does not happen automatically and I don't know why.

Here's how the Window.Top property currently is in the .XAML file:

```
Top="{Binding RecordingViewTop, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

And the double RecordingViewTop:

```
        private double _recordingViewTop;

        public double RecordingViewTop
        {
            get { return _recordingViewTop; }
            set
            {
                if (_recordingViewTop != value)
                {
                    _recordingViewTop = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

And here's my implementation of OnPropertyChanged():

```
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

I can't figure it out. When I debug my code, I can see that "RecordingViewTop" does get updated correctly, but somehow that doesn't transfer to the binding I made on Window.Top. How do I fix that?

UPDATE:
Here's the RecordingViewModel class:

```
public class RecordingViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private ICommand _moveCommand;
    public ICommand MoveCommand
    {
        get { return _moveCommand ??= new CommandHandler(() => Move(), () => true); }
    }

    private double _recordingViewTop;

    public double RecordingViewTop
    {
        get { return _recordingViewTop; }
        set
        {
            if (_recordingViewTop != value)
            {
                _recordingViewTop = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public RecordingViewModel() { }

    private void Move()
    {
        if (RecordingViewTop == 0)
        {
            _recordingViewTop = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - 150;
            MessageBox.Show(RecordingViewTop.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            _recordingViewTop = 0; 
            MessageBox.Show(RecordingViewTop.ToString());
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And here's how DataContext is currently set:

```
    public partial class RecordingView : Window
{
    public RecordingView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RecordingViewModel recordingViewModel = new RecordingViewModel();
        SetViewModel(recordingViewModel);
    }
    public RecordingView SetViewModel(RecordingViewModel recordingViewModel)
    {
        DataContext = recordingViewModel;
        return this;
    }
}
```

And this is my latest try for the XAML file:

```
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MoveCommand}"/>
        <i:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Top" Value="{Binding RecordingViewTop, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

As you can see, there's a MessageBox just to see if Move() is being called and if RecordingViewTop is getting updated accordingly, and that works fine if I move the mouse over the window, but the window doesn't move at all. Curiously, if I set "ChangePropertyAction" Value directly to a specific value, like "500", the window does move when the event is fired.

Comment: Does your View Model class implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) interface? You have the OnPropertyChanged code but the class also needs to specifically implement INotifyPropertyChanged (`: INotifyPropertyChanged` to the right of your class name).

Comment: It does. I'm wondering if I should do something to the View class, too? Or inside the XAML.

Comment: The XAML looks fine and overall this should be a pretty simple thing to do. I would double-check the Window's DataContext by adding a TextBlock in the Window: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding RecordingViewTop}" />`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that as well and the text isn't updating either. Both the text and the location of the window do change if I make some changes to the XAML while the code is running, though. For example, if I delete "Mode=TwoWay" and add it again, then it gets updated. I'm losing my mind over this

Comment: I suspect the issue is with INotifyPropertyChanged. Can you provide all the relevant code from your View Model?

Comment: Make sure the DataContext property of the Window is set to an instance of the view model and that the RecordingViewTop property of the same view model instance is modified on mouse over. Why don't you show us all necessary code to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Why do you have a view model at all? The most simple solution would be a MouseEnter event handler that directly updates Window.Top.

Comment: Check the Output-Window when you run your Code. Maybe you can see a Binding-Error there which gives you a hint where the problem is

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've updated my question to include all relevant code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in the XAML file you are binding the value to the public property "RecordingViewTop", while in the "Move" method you are updating its private var "_recordingViewTop".

Just change your "Move" method to:

```
private void Move()
{
    if (RecordingViewTop == 0)
    {
        RecordingViewTop = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - 150;
        MessageBox.Show(RecordingViewTop.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        RecordingViewTop = 0; 
        MessageBox.Show(RecordingViewTop.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my God. I feel so stupid right now. Your solution worked perfectly. Thank you so much!